# Caterpillar almost never moves

Tags: health, eating, exotic-pets

My caterpillar doesn't want to move, she stays still most of the time, i know she might be in the pupation process but, She is not yet in her "adult" form.And about harmful substances, I've been very careful about it...but in my mind it's the option that makes the most sense to me. Do you know anything else that might be happening to her? She is a "papillio cresphontes"
I've had other caterpillars of other species but this has never happened to me. They were active and very agitated...

Answer (score 1):

Now I found out what happened, she was shedding her skin!!! i didn't know caterpillars could do that lol i'm so relieved.

Comment: Yes, caterpillars usually pass through multiple instar stages before pupating, and moult between stages, have a look at this for a different species: https://www.activewild.com/monarch-caterpillar-stages/